# Progressive web calls old web hosted application

Tags: angular, win-universal-app, azure-web-app-service, progressive-web-apps

I have updated my azure hosted web site, one API location which my app visits has changed and it needed to be updated. When I run my web app directly it works fine but when I try debugging it in the visual studio progressive web (Universal App) to prepare it to be posted on Microsoft store it still calls the old API location.

How can I refresh the progressive web app so that it connects to the current version of my azure hosted web app ?

Comment: How did you call your website API in your app? Please provide more detailed information.

Comment: Sorry, I found the solution to the problem i needed to call the window.location.reload(true) in my website. It was a cache problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem, the web site called the data from cache and I all I had to do was reload it with window.location.reload(true). After that it pulled the new version.